# Script/wrapper for openssl which will download an entire certificate chain, and save each cert to a serparate file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, openssl, ksh

I've seen example such as the one below which download one cert using openssl, but am looking for one which will download the entire cert chain and save each as a separate file.  Ideally it would be great to save each cert file matching the name of the CN.

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect HOST:PORTNUMBER | \
  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because its asking for a software or program recommendation. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Or maybe [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) can help you out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, I dislike "write a program for me" type requests here, but in this case I realized I'd like to have such a thing myself, so I went ahead and wrote it. This isn't particularly polished, it just dumps the certs out into the current directory. One nice thing I did add is that it'll automatically enable the appropriate starttls mode for non-ssl services that `openssl s_client` supports it for (i.e. smtp, imap, pop3, ftp, and xmpp). . It also includes the summaries that openssl prints of each cert's subject and issuer in the cert files (before the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Connect to an SSL service and extract its certificates to files in the
# current directory.

usage() {
    echo "Usage:" >&2
    echo "  $(basename "$0") server[:port] [other s_client flags]" >&2
    echo "  $(basename "$0") protocol://server [other s_client flags]" >&2
    exit 1
}


# Parse command-line arguments
openssl_options=()
if (( $# < 1 )); then    # No server address specified
    usage

elif [[ "$1" = *://* ]]; then   # proto://domain format
    port="${1%%://*}" # Just use the protocol name as the port; let openssl look it up
    server="${1#*://}"
    server="${server%%/*}"

elif [[ "$1" = *:* ]]; then    # Explicit port number supplied
    port="${1#*:}"
    server="${1%:*}"

else # No port number specified; default to 443 (https)
    server="$1"
    port=443
fi

# If the protocol/port specified is a non-SSL service that s_client supports starttls for, enable that
if [[ "$port" = "smtp" || "$port" = "pop3" || "$port" = "imap" || "$port" = "ftp" || "$port" = "xmpp" ]]; then
    openssl_options+=(-starttls "$port")
elif [[ "$port" = "imap3" ]]; then
    openssl_options+=(-starttls imap)
elif [[ "$port" = "pop" ]]; then
    port=pop3
    openssl_options+=(-starttls pop3)
fi


# Any leftover command-line arguments get passed to openssl s_client
shift
openssl_options+=("$@")

# Try to connect and collect certs
connect_output=$(openssl s_client -showcerts -connect "$server:$port" "${openssl_options[@]}" </dev/null) || {
    status=$?
    echo "Connection failed; exiting" >&2
    exit $status
}
echo

nl=$'\n'

state=begin
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
    case "$state;$line" in
      "begin;Certificate chain" )
        # First certificate is about to begin!
        state=reading
        current_cert=""
        certname=""
        ;;

      "reading;-----END CERTIFICATE-----" )
        # Last line of a cert; save it and get ready for the next
        current_cert+="${current_cert:+$nl}$line"

        # Pick a name to save the cert under
        if [[ "$certname" = */CN=* ]]; then
            certfile="${certname#*/CN=}"
            certfile="${certfile%%/*}"
            certfile="${certfile// /_}.crt"
        elif [[ -n "$certname" && "$certname" != "/" ]]; then
            certfile="${certname#/}"
            certfile="${certfile//\//:}"
            certfile="${certfile// /_}.crt"
        else
            echo "???No name found for certificate" >&2
            certfile="Unknown_certificate.crt"
        fi

        # ...and try to save it
        if [[ -e "$certfile" ]]; then
            echo "Already exists: $certfile" >&2
        else
            echo "Saving cert: $certfile"
            echo "$current_cert" >"$certfile"
        fi

        state=reading
        current_cert=""
        certname=""
        ;;

      "reading; "*" s:"* )
        # This is the cert subject summary from openssl
        certname="${line#*:}"
        current_cert+="${current_cert:+$nl}Subject: ${line#*:}"
        ;;

       "reading; "*" i:"* )
        # This is the cert issuer summary from openssl
        current_cert+="${current_cert:+$nl}Issuer:  ${line#*:}"
        ;;

      "reading;---" )
        # That's the end of the certs...
        break
        ;;

      "reading;"* )
        # Otherwise, it's a normal part of a cert; accumulate it to be
        # written out when we see the end
        current_cert+="$nl$line"
        ;;
    esac
done 3<<< "$connect_output"
```

Comment: Necessity is the mother of invention -- or in this case the mother of a handy script. Great work.

Comment: Bad Ass!   

I assumed this existed already, but couldn't find anything like it.   Well done sir!

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/s_client.html):

> `-showcerts`: display the whole server certificate chain: normally only the server certificate itself is displayed.

If you really need multiple files, you just need to split the output of your command using something like `csplit` (or `awk`) by matching the beginning of each certificate (similar regex to the one in your command).